# is length method NSString's property?

Tags: objective-c, properties, nsstring

In NSString.h:

```
@interface NSString : NSObject <NSCopying, NSMutableCopying, NSCoding>

/* NSString primitive (funnel) methods. A minimal subclass of NSString just needs to implement these, although we also recommend getCharacters:range:. See below for the other methods.
*/
- (NSUInteger)length;           
- (unichar)characterAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;

@end
```

NSString didn't define length as a property, but we can use both [string length] and string.length.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot (.) syntax was added as part of Objective-C 2.0. You don't need to have something declared as a property to use the dot syntax.

Comment: Oh, I thought only property can use the dot syntax.Maybe I need to read the document about Objective-C 2.0's dot syntax.